# Why the size of the const char *arr is greater then const char arr[]?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, optimization

[image]I am using the xc32 compiler for the microchip pic32 microcontroller.

The program memory size (for the startup, vectors and etc..) is 1656 bytes.

```
#include <plib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

//if I use const char array[] for string literal then the size of the program memory increased 
//equal to the string length(only 12 bytes)

//const char array[] = "Hello World"; //program mem size(1668 0x684) bytes

//but in this case size increased 28 bytes
//const char *array = "Hello World";  //program mem size(1684 0x694) bytes



int main {

    while(1);
}
```

for optimization purposes:

which one is good(for both speed and size)?

1. #define STRLIT "HELLO WORLD"
2. const char *strlit = "HELLO WORLD";
3. const char arr[] = "HELLO WORLD"

Comment: What compilation options did you use? In my experience compilers would optimize out any differences once optimizations are turned on (and I could only observe differences with optimizations turned off)

Comment: The idiomatic way is `const char array[] = "Hello World";`. But `#define STRLIT "HELLO WORLD"` might more or less boil down to the latter, it depends on the platform/compiler and how you use `STRLIT`. Performance wise it most likely doesn't matter.

Comment: Instead of manually optimizing based on your options, try to use the compilers `-Osize` option (unless you know exactly what you are doing)

Comment: To answer your first question, the `const char *array` separately needs to store a pointer (8 bytes, allocated 16 bytes for alignment I think) and the string. The first version (the array) only needs to store the string. This happens because of the way you have declared them. `const char array[] = "..."` implies that the string needs to get stored. `const char *array` implies that the string needs to get stored, that there needs to be a global pointer, and that the pointer needs to point to the string.

Comment: @UnholySheep I am using optimization level -0, I added my configuration screenshot to the question

Comment: To answer your second question, it depends. Try to understand what macros do (hint: the preprocessor replaces all occurences of the macro with the string). To properly understand how the size and speed of your program is affected by each of your options, you need to better understand how they are implemented. As of now, I would encourage you to ignore such optimizations and instead learn to write good code. Once you get more familiar with the language, you will better understand the size/performanec implications.

Comment: @ewave, you can add `-Osize` in the additional options field.

Comment: All of the 3 will compile to the same thing even with basic optimisation.

Comment: @TGS array also behaves like a pointer, then what is the difference between both of them.

Comment: @ewave The difference is that `const char *arr` first creates an anonymous array and hen does `arr = anonymous_array`. There's not much of a difference other than `const char *` can be made to point to somewhere else but that's not a good idea.

Comment: Is PIC32 Von Neumann or Harvard? It seems rather relevant. According to  https://blog.flyingpic24.com/2008/10/26/pic32-harvard-or-von-neumann/ we should be able to program it as if it was Von Neumann (that is, no special tricks to store or access data in ROM).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, memory on a MCU is stored like this: [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102) This means:

- The *string literal* `"HELLO WORLD"` itself is very likely stored in a `.rodata` flash ROM section.
- When you do `const char array[] = "Hello World";` at file scope, the `array` variable should be allocated in `.rodata`. So there is no need to allocate the string literal or that would mean redundant allocation.
- When you do `const char *array` then you declare a pointer and it it is *not* allocated in flash, but in the `.data` section of RAM. So this will mean RAM and flash consumption both. Please note that this pointer is read/write - you can assign it somewhere else but you can't change the pointed-at contents.

  To allocate the pointer in flash ROM, you need to do `const char* const array`.

As for why you get "28 bytes" of something, I don't know. I haven't used this part but a brief research [here](https://blog.flyingpic24.com/2008/10/26/pic32-harvard-or-von-neumann/) claims that it might have Von Neumann characteristics, from the C programmers point of view, even though the core is Harvard. Not sure what that boils down to, but this matters since Harvard architectures might need to execute some support overhead code to access flash ROM data, which in turn leads to slightly larger executable size. You need to disassemble if you want to know the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences between your 3 options:

- `#define STRLIT "HELLO WORLD"` defines a preprocessor token: no code or data is generated in the executable, yet every instance of `STRLIT` in the code will be replaced with the string literal at compile time, which may generate more data or not.
- `const char arr[] = "HELLO WORLD"` defines a named array of `char` of size 12 bytes, initialized and null terminated. It takes 12 bytes in the executable read-only data segment, which may increase the size of the executable by 12 bytes or more depending on alignment constraints in the executable format.
- `const char *strlit = "HELLO WORLD";` defined both a string literal (a constant array of size 12 bytes) and a modifiable pointer `strlit` initialized to point to the string literal. This should at least use 4 bytes more in the executable (the size of a pointer on your 32-bit target system), but may increase the size of the executable by more than 4 bytes again depending on alignment constraints in the executable format.

Note also that depending on compiler options, there might be debugging data present in the executable file.

Comment: macros are not stored in the executable data, if you use `STRLIT` multiple times in the source code, depending on where you use them, and depending on compiler settings and/or optimisation features, the string may be duplicated in the executable or not. Most compilers share identical string literals or even string literals that are suffixes of other string literals, either from the same source file or even at link time. It really depends on your system, the C Standard allows for multiple solutions.